# ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I have a small game in which after the game is over the user is linked to a view that displays a leader board of all users and their scores. To do this I have treated the link as an update action so that the users score can be updated after the game is over, however, upon clicking the link I get an error saying "param is missing or the value is empty: user". I am also wondering if this is being caused because there is no form to be filled simply a variable being updated.

Controllers:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id 
        redirect_to '/play'
    else
        render '/'
    end
end

def update
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to '/leaderboard'
    else
        render '/play'
    end
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:nick_name, :score)
end
end



class ScoresController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_user, only: [:index]

def index
    @user = User.find(current_user)     
    @score = @user.score
    @score = 0
end

def leaderboard
    @users = User.all
end
end
```

View-link:

```
    <div class="game-over"><%= link_to 'Game Over', "/update", :style => 'text-decoration:none; color:white;' %></div>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#new', as: :users
  post '/' => 'users#create'

  get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/play' => 'scores#index', as: :user 
  get '/update' => 'users#update'
  get '/leaderboard' => 'scores#leaderboard'
```

Comment: when you read the rails guide regarding `CRUD` it says that `update` correspond to `PATCH/PUT` not `get`


 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: When I put patch/put I get an error saying no route matches [get]

Answer (score 0):

`user` has to be present in the request params because you required it in user_params. You can change link_to to use query parameters as follows:

```
link_to "Refresh", {controller: 'users', action: 'update', nick_name: "#{user.nick_name}", score: "#{get_score}"}, style: '...'
```

Or change update route to contain those parameters in the url.

```
# routes.rb
get '/update/:nick_name/:score' => 'users#update'
```

Tip: You probably should change it to PUT and use form instead, since update action alters state in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like whatever you are using to pass through your params to make the request is not properly nested under a user key.